# Problem with running react native app using appcenter-analytic

Tags: android, react-native, analytics

I've tried to make a react native app using 3 packages of "appcenter-analytics" and "appcenter-crashes" and "appcenter" for test.

I've done just like what was mentioned in Microsoft documentation (installing an linking the packages with the specified secret key) and when I want to run project with the code "react-native run-android", I face this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :appcenter-analytics.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :appcenter-analytics: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

android\settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'anatest'

include ':appcenter-crashes'
project(':appcenter-crashes').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android')
include ':appcenter-analytics'
project(':appcenter-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-analytic/android')
include ':appcenter'
project(':appcenter').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter/android')

include ':app'
```

android\app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anatest"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':appcenter-analytics')
    implementation project(':appcenter-crashes')

    implementation project(':appcenter')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

android\app\src\main\java\com\anatest\MainApplication.java

```
package com.anatest;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.crashes.AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics.AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage;
import com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.appcenter.AppCenterReactNativePackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new AppCenterReactNativeCrashesPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes)),
            new AppCenterReactNativeAnalyticsPackage(MainApplication.this, getResources().getString(R.string.appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics)),
            new AppCenterReactNativePackage(MainApplication.this)
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I also tried matching fallbacks in app\build.gradle with the code matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug'] also changing react native, wrapper and  gradle versions, but nothing worked out :(

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appcenter-analytics path is wrong.

In your android\settings.gradle

Change

```
include ':appcenter'
project(':appcenter').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter/android')
```

with

```
include ':appcenter-analytics'
project(':appcenter-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android')
```

Comment: its by default like this so and its throwing same error